# Proper use of C++ 'for each' options

Tags: c++, qt, boost, foreach, std

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10522155/594137) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523152/594137) have got me curious about the purpose of Boost and Qt's *for each* macros.

I've used Qt's and find the macro has always worked well enough for my needs but have never extensively tested its performance. I have not used Boost's offering before.

What I would like to know is when would be a good time to use the alternatives provided by Qt and Boost over `std::for_each`?

<sub>*Note: The wording has been changed from [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10524653/6) to make the question more objective.*</sub>

Comment: `std::for_each` has existed since at least C++98, so I'd be amazed if you found a compiler that _didn't_ support it. That being said, what you're asking for is essentially subjective, and thus not a good question for SO.

Comment: How can one offer a pro or con without giving one's opinion, which is subjective by definition?

Comment: You have the links to the documentation.  The documentation describes what the functions do.  Can you not derive the differences by comparing the descriptions?

Comment: In some cases you may not have to pay for parking with a car either, so no, we do not agree. The bottom line is that [Stack Overflow is not a List for All Things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128561/166663), [nor is it a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/166663), [nor is it your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/166663) -- there's just no way this question fits here IMO.

Comment: I have to pay for parking, but its only $1.25 rather than $2.00.

Comment: "And secondly, what are the differences, and (quantifiable) pros, and cons for each of the following?" All three come with source code. Read source, and differences, cons/pros should become fairly obvious

Comment: I'm not saying your question doesn't make sense, or that it's a bad question in any way; I'm only saying it isn't a good fit for SO. :-] You may want to try [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ildjarn:  I doubt PSE is the right place either -- they are not our dumping ground.  I don't think there's anywhere on SE where this question is not going to get closed.

Comment: That just means you're fundamentally misunderstanding SO's format.

Comment: How about using the new C++11 ranged for-loop, it is the easiest and best to work with and it is *standard*

Comment: @Yet: Because, while it is a standard feature of the language, C++11 is not *everywhere*. You have to have a compiler version that supports this construct, and quite a few widely used ones do not.

Comment: @NicolBolas As far as I can see the latest version of the three major compilers (VC++, GCC and Clang) all support range-based for-loops. If one can use it, it can well be preferred over any stl based implementation or non-standard implementation.

Comment: @Yet: Consider that the latest version of one of those compilers is still in *beta*. And yes, while it would be preferred where possible, that doesn't mean it is in fact possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose and functioning of `std::for_each` is very different from that of the macros `BOOST_FOREACH` and `Q_FOREACH`.

`std::for_each` is, first and foremost, a *function call*. It is an algorithm. You call it, providing a pair of iterators. On each member of the iterator range, it will call the given function with the value fetched from the iterator in question.

The purpose of `std::for_each`, conceptually speaking, is really to match up with the more specific algorithms that already exist. With algorithms like `count`, `copy`, etc, it makes sense to have one that simply executes arbitrary code for every element.

`BOOST_FOREACH` and `Q_FOREACH` are equivalent constructs (which I will collectively call `FOREACH`), but *behave* differently from `std::for_each`.

`FOREACH` is, first and foremost, a *for loop*. Now, that might not sound so different, but think about it. You cannot call `continue` and `break` from within `std::for_each`. `continue` can be emulated easily enough with `return` (though this also means you can't return from the function that issues the `std::for_each` call). But there's no way to escape from the `std::for_each` loop if you want to stop. Similarly, you can't `goto` out of a `for_each` loop. The best you can do in either case is throw an exception, and that's using exceptions for flow control (ie: not a good idea).

When you use `std::for_each`, you must provide some callable function. This could be a function pointer or function object. Because of that, your code is somewhat de-localized. This is fine if what you're doing in each iteration is a complex, multi-line function. But if each iteration's logic is quite simple, then code readability decreases a bit.

`FOREACH` executes a local block of code. So the code is right there; you don't have to track down a function to see what's happening on each iteration.

Also, calling a function means having to write that function. If you need to keep track of state, you now need a functor, which requires more code to write.

C++11 makes `std::for_each` *much* more attractive with lambda functions. This removes the code locality problem: the source code is right there. And since lambdas can capture stuff, it can work almost exactly like a regular `for` loop. Well, except for no `break` functionality, but that's usually avoidable.

Of course, C++11 also makes it effectively *obsolete* (along with `FOREACH`) with range-based `for` loops. But since there are different levels of conformance with C++11, there are some environments where you have lambda but not range-based `for`.

What you *ought* to use is up to you. `FOREACH` is nice, and if you're already using Boost and/or Qt, then feel free. But I wouldn't suddenly start using these just for `FOREACH`. Personally, I wouldn't use `std::for_each` unless you're also using lambdas or something, due to code locality issues. Just use a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, your clarification of use cases was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

`std::for_each` is part of the C++ Standard, and has been since 1998 (at least).  Hence any (not-so) modern C++ is *non-compliant* and therefore broken if it doesn't provide `for_each`.  All compilers I use on a daily basis support it.

Both of the libraries you mention live outside the C++ language itself.  `for_each` is the only one that is guaranteed to be present in a conformant compiler.

As for pros and cons, I leave that to you to decide.  Given a choice, I'll go with something guaranteed by the Standard over something that's not.

Comment: is for_each faster in terms of speed than the normal looping mechanisms ?

Comment: The Standard says it runs in O(n) time.  In every implementation I've seen, it's just a for loop that is at least as fast as anything you could write in a general sense.

Comment: That being said, *speed of execution* is neither a typical reason to use `for_each`, nor is it a reason not to.

Comment: my question was not about time complexity any looping(for, for_each, while) would work in O(n). my question was are there overheads in using for_each than using standard for. THanks.

Comment: It's an `inline` function call.  All else is implementation-defined but, as I said, I've never seen an implementation that is worse than hand-written code.  I suggest you take a look at *your* implementation if this is a major concern.

Answer (score 1):

std::for_each requires a **functor**, **lambda** or **function-pointer** to execute. Using it you can avoid a lot of boilerplate if you loop the same methods at several places in your code.

```
 void hello(int i){
      printf("World %d \n",i);
 }

 std::vector<int> vals;
 vals.push_back(1);
 vals.push_back(2);
 std::for_each(vals.begin(),vals.end(),hello);
```

BOOST_FOREACH and Q_FOREACH are used to hide the boilerplate of c++ iterators, they replace the normal for-statement and loop over the loop body.

```
  for(vector<int>::iterator iter = vals.begin();iter != vals.end();++iter)
  {
      hello(*iter);
  }

  Q_FOREACH(int val, vals){
      hello(val);
  }
```

Usage: Which ever you think is most readable and avoids unnecessary code duplication.

Performance: every one of these is either a macro or a template function and completely visible to the compiler, differences should only exist in debug builds if at all.