# QstringList to Qstring conversion issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am working on VS2015 with qt framework. In my source code, I have a function for printing in the GUI screen.
This function is called each time something needs to be printed. 
It goes like this.

```
void Trial::Print_MessageBox(QString string)
{

    ui.MessagesScreen->appendPlainText(string); 
    Cursor_Messagebox.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
    ui.MessagesScreen->setTextCursor(Cursor_Messagebox);
    ui.MessagesScreen->ensureCursorVisible();
}

// Output in MessageBox
void Trial::Print_MessageBox(QFlags<QNetworkInterface::InterfaceFlag> flags)
{
    QString str = QString("Flag %1").arg(flags);
    ui.MessagesScreen->appendPlainText(str);
}
```

The above function has no problems and running well.

Now I am trying to read a text file. This has set of values in no order or size. An example for this:

231, 54, 4 \n

47777, 2211, 676, 9790, 34236, 7898\n

1, 3\n

Objective is to convert these into integers (line by line) and print them in the GUI and also send them (line by line) to other system. So I tried to do it with the following.

```
void Trial::ReadFile_Data()
{
    QFile file("input.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        Print_MessageBox("Error in reading File");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        Print_MessageBox(line);
        int conv = line.toInt();
        QString str = QString("%1 %2").arg("Values are: ").arg(conv);
        Print_MessageBox(str);
        QStringList fields = line.split(",");
    }
    file.close();
}
```

When I print the "line", it is just printing the same values as in the file. When I do the conversion and printing, I get an error (which is expected) Now I try to remove "," with the help of split then I get QstringList which I cannot use as I have the Qstring function to print(this cant be changed)

I am not getting any pointers from here. Please help me out as this is bugging me since long time.

Comment: Iterate the string list a print each of the strings in it

Answer (score 0):

Just simple...

```
QStringList::const_iterator constIterator;

for (constIterator = fonts.constBegin(); constIterator != fonts.constEnd();
           ++constIterator) {

        cout << (*constIterator).toLocal8Bit().constData() << endl;
}
```

where fonts is your QStringlist

Comment: Simpler: `for (const auto& font : fonts) { cout << font.toLocal8Bit().constData() << endl; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your question reduces to "How do I iterate over a `QStringList`".

Like this:

```
// C++11
for (auto field : fields) Print_messageBox(field);
// C++98
foreach (QString field, fields) Print_messageBox(field);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10522155/1329652) for information about how `foreach` a.k.a `Q_FOREACH` was implemented.