# C++ QT Delete QNetworkCookie

Tags: c++, qt, cookies

I am trying to delete a cookie but am getting the error:

`error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const QNetworkCookie' to 'QNetworkCookie &'`

I am confused why the compiler is complaining about `const QNetworkCookie` (I am assuming it is complaining about my `foreach()`).

```
void PersistentCookieJar::deleteCookie(const QString cookieName) {
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = allCookies();
    foreach(QNetworkCookie &cookie, allCookies()) {
        if (cookie.name() == cookieName) {
            cookie.setValue(""); // delete the cookie
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void PersistentCookieJar::deleteCookie(const QString cookieName) {
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = allCookies();
    foreach(QNetworkCookie &cookie, cookies) {
        if (cookie.name() == cookieName) {
            cookie.setValue(""); // delete the cookie
            break;
        }
    }
    setAllCookies(cookies);
}
```

Comment: `QList<QNetworkCookie> QNetworkCookieJar::allCookies() const`. So compiler is complaining because allCookes() is returning a const? How would I change how `allCookies()` returns my `QList`?

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing it only wants you to work with setters and getters. So you need to copy the whole list, edit the list, then set the cookies to your new list. Going to edit my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic difference between Qt's range for (`Q_FOREACH`, `foreach`) and  its C++11's homonymous: you cannot use Qt's one for modifying the elements of a container.

The reason is that Qt's implementation returns a constant reference for each element, while C++11 can work with non-const references. In your case, you are trying to initialize a reference from a constant (the one that `Q_FOREACH` returns), so you get a compilation error. As you see, it has nothing to do with the constness of the `allCookies()` method.

If instead of the `Q_FOREACH` you directly use iterators or indices to iterate your container, then you are accessing the actual elements so you can modify them.

This code snippet illustrates some possible ways (wrong and correct) to iterate using `Q_FOREACH` (exhaustive iterator versions obviated for simplicity):

```
QList<QString> stringlist; // applies to any element type
stringlist.append("foo");

// 1, compiles but doesn't modify the list since 's' is a copy
foreach (QString s, stringlist) {
  s += "bar";
}
qDebug() << stringlist;

// 2, doesn't compile ('s' is constant and cannot be modified)
/*foreach (const QString& s, stringlist) {
  s += "bar";
}*/

// 3, equivalent to 1, compiles but doesn't modify the list
foreach (auto s, stringlist) {
  s += "bar";
}
qDebug() << stringlist;

// 4 (your case), doesn't compile, 's' cannot be initialized from a constant
/*foreach (QString& s, stringlist) {
  s += "bar";
}*/

// 5, using indices
for (int ii = 0; ii < stringlist.count(); ++ii) {
  stringlist[ii] += "bar";
}
qDebug() << stringlist;

// 6, using iterators
for (auto it = stringlist.begin(); it != stringlist.end(); ++it) {
  *it += "bar";
}
qDebug() << stringlist;
```

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10522155/1485885) for more info about how the `Q_FOREACH` macro works.