# Why is this allocating an unneeded temporary container

Tags: c++, qt, foreach, containers

I am getting a warning against my foreach loop that I'm "allocating an unneeded temporary container" but I have no idea what that means.

```
foreach(QString commandName, m_registeredResponseObjects.keys()) {
    delete m_registeredResponseObjects[commandName];
};
```

Does this means the key() method is called on each iteration of the loop?  I don't even see the container the warning is referencing...

foreach is a Qt macro defined as

```
template <typename T>
class QForeachContainer {
public:
    inline QForeachContainer(const T& t) : c(t), brk(0), i(c.begin()), e(c.end()) { }
    const T c;
    int brk;
    typename T::const_iterator i, e;
};
```

Comment: Where is `foreach` coming from? That's not standard C++.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271359/how-to-pass-an-object-address-created-at-time-of-function-call), please try to make a [mre].

Comment: Whichever language it turns out to be (the syntax doesn't match `foreach` in C# or `forEach` in Java), the answer is *probably* going to be that you should make `commandName` a *reference* variable. How to do that depends completely on the language.

Comment: my guess ' foreach' is a macro that does roughly what a ranged for does.(from before ranged for). But we need to see it

Comment: @pm100 Good guess: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10522155/10871073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you create a container with this statement: `m_registeredResponseObjects.keys()` for no good reason. This function iterates over your m_registeredResponseObjects, collects all keys and returns a container where you then iterator over just the get the values from m_registeredResponseObjects by key.
This makes no sense at all - why not simply

```
  for (auto val : qAsConst(m_registeredResponseObjects))
    delete val;
```

or even simpler with the Qt macro qDeleteAll()

```
  qDeleteAll(m_registeredResponseObjects);
```

?

Comment: This is new to me....m_registeredResponseObjects is a QMap<QString,myObj*> so will this for loop fill val with the pointer of each map entry?  (How does it know not to return the key)?  I couldn't find a good explanation of qAsConst used like this

Comment: Simply try it out - Qt containers do return the value in a range-based for loop. And even if you don't trust it, use Q_FOREACH as in your example... For qAsConst -> see the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qAsConst)