# C++ lifespan of temporary object passed to constructor

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, istream, temporary-objects

I have a class that accepts an istream reference in the constructor. If the constructor is passed a temporary object like `myclass obj(ifstream("filename"));` will that ifstream be good for the life of `obj`? Does it depend on whether or not it is assigned to a reference or pointer in the class?

For example:

```
class test
{
public:
    istream *p;
    test(istream &is)
    {
        p = &is;
        cout << "a constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~test()
    {
        cout << "a destructor" << endl;
    }
    bool isgood()
    {
        return p->good();
    }
};

int main()
{
    test test(ifstream("test.cpp"));
    cout << test.isgood() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a constructor
1
a destructor
```

Just because the output says the file is good I don't know if it's been destroyed or what. If there is a part of the standard that covers this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile...

Comment: the ifstream will close at the end of the block and be invalid after that. `p` will point to garbage

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010. @Josh the end of which block? I'm trying to figure out if the fstream that's opened in the constructor is valid until the end of main(). Thanks

Comment: It is hard to answer the question, because your code uses a non-standard "extension" to the language. So you have to look it up in your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't know what the nonstandard extension is and I would like to write portable code so please tell me what I should change.

Comment: Initialize the `ifstream` in `main` before `test`, and pass a reference to the `test` constructor.

Comment: Temporary objects aren't standard?

Comment: Temporary objects are standard, but binding a non-`const` lvalue reference function parameter (like `istream& is`) to one is not.

Comment: Oh boy. Is there a good resource that explains the difference in depth? I'm programming in Visual Studio and I thought it was normal to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why lifetime of temporary doesn't extend till lifetime of enclosing object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936720/why-lifetime-of-temporary-doesnt-extend-till-lifetime-of-enclosing-object)

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the link that's a pretty good discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

The temporary `istream` is good only in the constructor. Even though you use the address of the `istream` to set the value of the pointer, you can no longer use it once the constructor has returned. Since after the constructor call, the temporary ifstream has already been closed and destructed. So the pointer will be pointing to garbage as @Josh mentioned. You may modify your code to pass the filename into the constructor and use the filename to initialize an member `ifstream` (not a pointer to ifstream). Then you can use the stream through the lifespan of the object.