# What is the life span of an automatic bound to a lamba function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

If an automatic is bound to a lambda function, does the life of the automatic get extended to the life of the lambda function?

Simplest case:

```
auto genfunc (int start)
{
     int count=start;
     return [&count] {
         return count++;
     };
}
```

Is this fine, or undefined behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the lifetime of `count` is not extended because you capture it by reference. [Lifetime extension rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937829/241631) are listed in *§12.2 [class.temporary]*, items 4 & 5, and neither include capture by reference in a lambda.

Invoking the lambda returned by `genfunc` will result in undefined behavior. This is mentioned in a note in *§5.1.2/24 [expr.prim.lambda]*

> [ *Note:* If an entity is implicitly or explicitly captured by reference, invoking the function call operator of the corresponding lambda-expression after the lifetime of the entity has ended is likely to result in undefined
>   behavior. *—end note* ]

Comment: @vsoftco gcc-5.1 does [produce a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3858dd947c230f0), but it's not the most intuitive warning I've seen. clang just prints out garbage.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to expect C++ to catch this kind of thing. Unless C++ goes full [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29), it will never be possible to catch everything. It's nice that some blatant code is warned about, e.g. `return count;`, but this is complex.

Answer (score 5):

> does the life of the automatic get extended to the life of the lambda function?

No. The lambda might be confusing here, so let's rewrite it to be a struct:

```
struct X
{
    int operator()() const { return ref++; }

    int& ref;
};

auto genfunc (int start)
{
    int count=start;
    return X{count};
}
```

The `X` object that we created holds a reference (`ref`) to a temporary (`count`) that goes out of scope as soon as the object is returned. There's nothing special about the lambda - a dangling reference is a dangling reference.

There's no reason to keep the reference though, just capture by-value:

```
auto genfunc (int start)
{
     return [start]() mutable {
         return start++;
     };
}
```

Note the required `mutable` keyword.