# Returning an rvalue - what is wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I came across the following code snippet

```
std::string&& test()
{
    std::string m="Hello";
    return (std::move(m));
}

int main()
{
     std::string&& m = test();
}
```

I understand the above code is incorrect and unsafe but I am not sure why. 
So far this is my understanding of the code. In the function `test`

1. a local `std::string` variable called `m` is created on the stack.
2. This string is then returned however instead of a copy being made its contents are moved to the temporary. At this point the function `test` ends calling the destructor of variable `m` (whose contents were moved to the temp)
3. The temporary is now bound to the rvalue reference `m`. And from what I understand is that a temporary will remain alive until its binding object is alive and in scope .

Could someone please tell me where I might be going wrong ? Why is the code above unsafe ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An rvalue reference is still a reference, your code is incorrect for the same reason as the function shown below

```
std::string& test()
{
    std::string m="Hello";
    return m;
}
```

In both cases, the function returns a reference to a local variable. [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) doesn't do anything other than cast `m` to `string&&`, so there is no temporary created that `m` in `main` then binds to. When `test` exits, the local variable is destroyed, and `m` is a dangling reference.

To fix your code, change the return type from `string&&` to `string`.

```
std::string test()
{
    std::string m="Hello";
    return m;   // std::move is redundant, string will be moved automatically
}

int main()
{
     std::string&& m = test();
}
```

Now the `m` in `main` can bind to the return value of `test`, and the [lifetime of that is extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937829/241631) to match that of `m`.