# Create a non-temporary object in a constructor in c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, derived-class

I have a simple structure of abstract class `Animal` and a class `Dog` derived from it. I want to keep different `Animals` in `Cage` using a pointer to `Animal`. I would like to be able to create a `Dog` inside of a `Cage` constructor but it creates a temporary object which I can't point to:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal() {}
    virtual ~Animal() {}
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
public:
    ~Dog() {}
};

class Cage
{
public:
    const Animal* animal;
    Cage(Animal *anim): animal(anim) {}
};

int main()
{
    Dog doggy;
    Cage cage(&doggy); //works fine

    Cage new_cage(&Dog()); //error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]|
}
```

Is there any way to change the code, e.g. `Cage`'s constructor, so that the object created in it's constructor would be non-temporary?

EDIT: It seems like it could be done using dynamic allocation but this question was marked as a duplicate of this question

[Why lifetime of temporary doesn't extend till lifetime of enclosing object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936720/why-lifetime-of-temporary-doesnt-extend-till-lifetime-of-enclosing-object) , although it's a different question. I asked for any way to make that happen and not for extending a lifetime of a temporary. I would be grateful to πάντα ῥεῖ if he could explain how my question has an answer in this one's answers.

Comment: You're not creating any objects in `Cage`'s constructor.

Comment: You need to dynamically allocate the `Animal`.

Comment: @FeiXiang well that is not necessary either, the "works fine" version is fine

Comment: @M.M I assumed the OP wanted the `Cage` object to take ownership of the `Animal`.

Comment: It is fine, although having more complex hierarchy i would rather not create every single object this way as the would be clear enough.

Comment: @FeiXiang that's indeed what I wanted. I don't need to have a variable `doggy` like here. Much better would be, if I could get into all the `Animal`s by choosing the right `Cage` and accessing an `Animal` from it

Comment: You could use `std::unique_ptr` for the `Animal` pointer member of `Cage`. This would allow `Cage` to take ownership of the `Animal`.

Comment: @zett42 how would I do that? I need the object to keep it's type of `Dog` so I can't call `new Animal(anim)` in a constructor

Comment: Have the constructor take an `Animal` pointer and pass it to the constructor of the `std::unique_ptr` member in the constructor member initialization list. The constructor would look like `Cage(Animal *anim) : animal(anim) {}`. Now you can do `Cage cage(new Dog)`.

Comment: I would let the constructor take a `std::unique_ptr` parameter, to make it clear that ownership is transfered. A raw pointer parameter would not tell you that. Sure, you could document that, but self-documenting code is much better. [Live demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d34d73b56525788).