# A tuple of references as a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, temporary-objects

I do not understand well enough why the second call of `func` in the code below does not work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using Tuple = std::tuple<const int&, const std::string&>;

void func(const Tuple& t)
{
    std::cout << std::get<1u>(t) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 3;
    const std::string text = "xyz";
    
    func(Tuple(n, text));

    //Does not work:
    //func(Tuple(5, "abc"));

    return 0;
}
```

When is the temporary string `"abc"` destroyed?

**EDIT1**

So, finally, according to 康桓瑋 this works:

```
    func(Tuple(5, std::string("abc")));
```

but this does not:

```
    Tuple t(5, std::string("abc"));
    func(t);
```

right? If yes what is the difference?

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe its because the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference it is bound to (the one in Tuple's constructor), so by the time you call func, the temporary string has been destroyed already and you're basically in UB land by that point. [this question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936720/why-lifetime-of-temporary-doesnt-extend-till-lifetime-of-enclosing-object)

Answer (score 11):

Your second case is exactly what the standard wants to detect and forbid.

Since `"abc"` is *not* a `std::string` type, quote from [P2255](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2255r2.html#motivation):

> ```
> std::tuple<const std::string&> t("meow");
> ```
>
> > This construction always creates a dangling reference, because the
> > `std::string` temporary is created inside the selected constructor of
> > `tuple` (`template<class... UTypes> tuple(UTypes&&...)`), and not outside
> > it. Thus, unlike `string_view`’s implicit conversion from rvalue
> > `string`s, under no circumstances can this construction be correct.

And `Tuple(5, "abc")` is **no longer well-formed** in C++23 thanks to [P2255](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2255r2.html).

To prevent the destruction of temporary strings, you can explicitly specify the `std::string` type such as `func(Tuple(5, std::string("abc")))`.

Comment: But that example is a *named* object that has a lifetime that extends past the statement.  The OP's example is an unnamed Tuple object which has the same lifetime as the unnamed std::string object, so there will be no dangling.

Comment: @ChrisDodd This tuple is dangling as soon as it is constructed. Because we leave the constructor.

Comment: `func(Tuple(5, std::string("abc")))` works with GCC.

Comment: I did not understand the difference between `std::string("abc")` and `"abc"`. My understanding was that `"abc"` converted `std::string("abc")`, right?

Comment: @Alexey Starinsky For `tuple<const string&>(string("abc"))`, `const string&` is bound to the temporary `string("abc")` you pass in; But for `"abc"`, `const string&` is bound to a temporary `string` variable created *inside* the `tuple` constructor, which is destroyed at the end of the constructor.

Comment: @康桓瑋 For `tuple<const string&>(string("abc"))`, when is `string("abc")` destroyed?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinskyA When the expression `tuple<const string&>(string("abc"))` ends.

Answer (score 3):

As hinted at in the comments, the problem is not with the parameter to the call to `func`, *per se*, but with the second parameter to the `Tuple` constructor.

You are attempting to assign a reference to a string constructed as a temporary object (from the given `const char*` literal) to the second member of the tuple; when the constructor has completed/returned, that reference will invalid.

Some compilers *may* accept the code (MSVC does) and it *may* seem to work. However, clang-cl (in Visual Studio 2022) gives the following error when uncommenting the 'offending' line in your code:

> error : reference member '_Val' binds to a temporary object whose
> lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object

However, note the the **exact same error** is shown if we replace your one-line call to `func` with the following two lines:

```cpp
    Tuple tup = Tuple(5, "abc"); // Error on this line
    func(tup);
```

Comment: Seems like clang's error message is patently wrong -- the lifetime of the temporary object bound is *the same* as the lifetime of the Tuple it is bound in.  If you explicitly bind the Tuple to a name (which the OP does not do), only then is the lifetime of the Tuple extended and dangling problem occurs.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Not 100% sure, but I think the lifetime of the temporary string ends when the tuple's constructor ends, irrespective of whether that constructs a named/unnamed object.