# What's wrong with my simple thread-safe stack?

Tags: c++, multithreading

What's wrong with the following code? I just try to set up a quite simple thread-safe stack, when I run several threads to concurrently push and pop on the stack, then it sometimes reports 0xC0000005 exception.

```
#include <stack>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>


template<class T> class Stack{
    typedef stack < shared_ptr<T>, list<shared_ptr<T>>> Stack_;
public:
    Stack(){}
    Stack(const Stack& other){
        lock_guard<mutex>(other.mtx_);
        stack_ = other.stack_;
    }
    void push(shared_ptr<T> value){
        lock_guard<mutex>(this->mtx_);
        stack_.push(value);
    }
    shared_ptr<T> pop(){
        lock_guard<mutex>(this->mtx_);
        if (stack_.empty()) return nullptr;
        auto res = stack_.top();
        stack_.pop();
        return res;
    }
private:
    mutex mtx_;
    Stack_ stack_;
};
```

Comment: Where is your null pointer exception happening?

Comment: So, `Stack_stack_` is supposed to be `Stack_ stack_`?

Comment: Your copies of your stack use different mutexes (making synchronization obsolete)

Comment: You're getting a reference to the item on the top of the stack, and then calling pop, which calls that item's destructor.

Comment: @jakebower it's safe, it's a shared_ptr

Comment: Ah, good call.  Promptly overlooked that in the typedefs.

Comment: Time to break out your debugger.

Answer (score 7):

The main problem I see is you are not locking your resources properly.

This:

```
lock_guard<mutex>(this->mtx_); // temporary
```

That will unlock immediately after you locked it because it is a temporary and only lives until the `;`.

You should create a named variable like this:

```
lock_guard<mutex> lock(this->mtx_); // lives till end of scope
```

**See:** [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298781/why-do-un-named-c-objects-destruct-before-the-scope-block-ends) for information on temporary objects.

Comment: Also [this](http://kera.name/articles/2012/05/when-is-a-scoped-lock-not-a-scoped-lock/)