# Does C++ destruct object in given compound?

Tags: c++, scope, lifetime

Imagine a scenario:

```
class B {
  int f2() { return 5; }
}

class A {
  B f1() { B b1(); return b1; }
}

A var;
int p = var.f1().f2();
```

When I call `f1()`, an instance of class `B` gets created. Then, on return, a temporary copy gets created and returned. Now my question is since I'm immediately calling `f2()` on that returned object, will it immediately be deleted once `f2` returns? Or will it live until the end of the scope? Is there any rule describing this scenario or is it compiler dependent?

Comment: Have you tried to add a destructor with a print to test your hypothesis? If so, what did you see and why did it confuse you?

Comment: I want to know if what I saw was accidental (so called "undefined behaviour"), or governed by standards

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/q/584824/5987 helpful, even if it's not exactly the same question. Temporary variables will last until the end of the full expression, but not beyond.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do un-named C++ objects destruct before the scope block ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298781/why-do-un-named-c-objects-destruct-before-the-scope-block-ends)

Comment: Note that `B b1();` declares a function named `b1` that returns a `B` ([see demo](https://ideone.com/a0YLO4)).  It does not declare an object named `b1` of type `B`.  To do that, you need to remove the parenthesis: `B b1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporaries live until the end of the full expression, which in your case is marked by the `;`. So the code is perfectly safe and the `p` will be initialized with `5`.

See

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

for more details.

**EDIT**: your code works, aside from @Remy's comment, read about the [Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) for more details.