# What is the definition of definition

Tags: c++, definition

What does **definition** mean in the c++ standard's context? Several definitions of the same name are accepted in the different scopes:

```
int a=1;

int main()
{
    int a=1;
}
```

It is unclear what actually ODR does mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local variable scope question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388685/local-variable-scope-question)

Comment: Scoping disambiguates definitions.

Comment: Names don't have definitions in the ODR sense. Objects, functions and other such things do.

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to here does not come under ODR since the scope of the variable has changed.

> A name (other than a statement label) has block scope if it's
>   declared within a function definition (including that function's
>   parameter list) or in a brace-enclosed block within that function. Its
>   scope begins right after its declaration and runs to the end of the
>   block immediately enclosing that declaration.

You can read the rest of the article here: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/scope-regions-in-c/240002006